# How to parse std::list to json::value in casablanca?

Tags: c++, rest, c++17, casablanca

I'm trying to parse std::list to json::value with casablanca1.2.0 with Visual Studio 2012 and send JSON request with REST service(POST) from C++ application to Java Application.

REST service requires a request DTO like this.

```
// java
public class MyProfile {
 private String name;
 private List<String> favoriteFood;
 ...
}
```

So I tried to write C++ code, but I couldn't find how to convert std::list to json::value.

```
// C++
std::wstring name = "AAA";
std::list<std::wstring> favoriteFood = ...;

json::value requestData;
requestData[L"name"] = json::value::string(name);

std::vector<json::value::string> vvv;
for (auto itr = favoriteFood.begin(); itr != favoriteFood.end(); ++itr) {
 vvv.push_back(json::value::string(*itr));
}
requestData[L"favoriteFood"] = json::value::array(vvv); // compile error occurs
```

I'm totally new to Casablanca and JSON, so I can't find any solution.

Any help would be very nice!!!

Comment: What error are you getting?  What json library are you using?

Comment: error C2665 occurs.

JSON library... Sorry, I don't know where to find it's name in calablanca casablanca110.sln...